# Android: What is the right approach to returning values from an anonymous class to thread?

Tags: java, android, anonymous-class

What modification is needed for getVehicleName () function to return vehicle name correctly to the parent thread? What will be the best approach? I tried handler and call back functions, but ended up with compile time errors ("attempting to assign weaker access privileges").

Parent function (complete code not pasted)

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    boolean val = checkifVehicleAvailable("1111A");
                } catch (Exception e){
                }
            });
```

Functions

```
 public boolean checkifVehicleAvailable(String drive_this) {

     if( getVehicleName(drive_this).equals("1111A"){     
     return true;
     }
     return false;
}

// Need to be modified to return String 

public String getVehicleName(String ID){
    /*DB references*/
    //final String vehicleName;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    DatabaseReference childRef;

    myRef = database.getReference();
    childRef = myRef.child("vehicles");
    childRef.child(ID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        String vehicleSecretName;
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             vehicleName = dataSnapshot.child("vehicleName").getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please, format your code. In the first part you use `try` without `catch`. You write `getVehicleName(drive_this).equals("1111A")`, but getVehicleName is void.

Comment: Edited. I am looking for the right approach to modify getVehicleName() to return the string value from firebase DB.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the value inside the SharedPreferences and register a SharedPreferenceListener to notify this listener if a certain value has changed. The listener could look like that:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
     if(key.equals("myKey") { 
        sharedPreferences.getString(key); 
        //do whatever after that > e.g. start your async task or load that value into an AsyncTask via execute(..) method.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you coult for example say:

```
    final boolean[] result = new boolean[1];

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            boolean val = foo();
            result [0] = val;
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
    });
 }

private boolean foo(){
    return false;
}
```